# jQuery issue in local system

Tags: jquery

When I setup projects from live server to local system there is issue with jQuery. Not working in local system while on live server its working fine. I updated latest jQuery in local but not working still. So can't find solutions for that how to resolve. And there is no errors on live server.

```
SyntaxError: illegal character[Learn More]  jquery-ui.min.js:5:15421
unreachable code after return statement[Learn More]  Ajaxfileupload-jquery-1.3.2.js:19:13091
SyntaxError: illegal character[Learn More]  Ajaxfileupload-jquery-1.3.2.js:19:15176
TypeError: $ is not a function[Learn More]
```

Comment: `$ is not a function`. Are you including `jQuery` library before you use it?

Comment: What is your local system?